# Div background not coming through in IE 7, 8 & IE 9 / no scroll in IE 8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

We're polishing this site: dev.underglassframing.com

Everything works great in every browser, except the background behind the main content div (#main) is stopping before the content in IE 7, 8 & 9.  I included a clear:both div at the end, and the background is not continuing.

Secondly, the site is not scrolling at all in IE8!!  I have no idea what is happening.  Any help at all would be so wonderful!

Thanks!
Jennifer

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to reside in this portion of your code:

```
body {
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/index_bg.png', sizingMethod='scale')
}
```

IE filter's can cause some strange display issues at times, and eliminating this seemed to correct all the problems you described (including IE8 scroll). For the background, that filter seems to be cutting off the rendering of your `#main` background at the bottom of where ever the browser window is.

Since you already have the `background-image: url("images/index_bg.png")` set, I'm not even sure why you feel the need to have the `filter` code. I cannot detect any change (other than it all working as you want) by removing it.

Comment: @user1132975--if it works for you, the custom is to click the "check mark" at the left to show that you "accept" the answer.